# Problemas con zona horaria en Servidor Hostinger

Tags: php7, host

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
    // Unix
    setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_MX.UTF-8');
    // En windows
    setlocale(LC_TIME, 'spanish');
    ini_set('date.timezone', 'America/Mexico_City');
```

Subí en Hostinger mi página y cuando creo un artículo me aparece la hora de diferencia de +4 horas, traté de cambiarla con todos los códigos anteriores pero no resulta ¿Dónde se supone que debo poner el código? Lo puse en el archivo de configuraciones que todos los demás son ramificados de ahí, ¿lo pongo dónde? Ya me estreso bastante

La versión que le puse de PHP al servidor es PHP 7.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No solo debes incorporar `date_default_timezone_set("America/Mexico_City")`o `date.timezone = "America/Mexico_City"`que lo pones al inicio de tu script PHP. También debes ver si el servidor tiene la hora correcta. Eso lo haces con el comando `date` directamente desde la línea de comando. Si la hora que te aparece es distinta a la que deseas, debes corregirla de la siguiente forma:

Con el comando:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

Te va a aparecer algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ojo si no lo tienes instalado, lo instalas con `sudo apt-get install -y tzdata`

Puedes configurar la zona y luego puedes cambiar la hora directamente con el comando (o no dependiendo de la hora con que te quedó):

```
date --set "13:10:30"
```

Finalmente no olvides que también deberías corregir la zona horaria de Mysql si es que aplica a tu sistema:

```
[MySql]
mysql = SET time_zone = '-3:00';
```

Comment: Me sigue poniendo que fue hace tantas horas, http://onelastwords.com/ publico algo y me dice que fue hace más tiempo del actual, no sé si Hostinger tenga para configurar el php ini, no me da permisos para editar el mysql

Comment: Y ya le añadí el date_default_timezone_set("America/Mexico_City") al inicio de todas las ramificaciones de los archivos php ¿o es en cada uno?

Comment: Ya lo puse en todas partes y no sé que hacer :c

Comment: El Hostinger es de paga :c Así que no sé qué onda con las configuraciones de comandos

Comment: Creo que para entrar a los comandos tengo que pagar más :v

Comment: Mira haz pruebas de a poco para descartar: 1.- chequea la hora del servidor. 2.-haz una página test.php en blanco solo con un echo date("H:i:s") con y sin tu zona horaria. Chequea que paso 3.- haz una tabla de test en MYSQL solo con un par de campos de lo cuales uno se de fecha y haz un insert desde tu página test.php.  Con esto sabras cual de los 3 niveles tiene el problema y tendrás un buen argumento para hablar con el soporte de Hostinger (atienden bien) No hay que pagar más , yo tengo un VPS de US6 /mes en Hostinger y anda bien

Comment: Oh, gracias por el consejo, en serio se aprecia bastante

Comment: En la base de datos la hora es 17:57:06 cuando son las 12:57, cinco horas de diferencia

Comment: Haciendo el date me da que son 12:59:07 siendo 12:59 supongo que ahí no falló

Comment: ¿Cómo se habla con el suporte? Hasta dónde yo sé, no tienen teléfonos

Comment: Quién sabe cómo, ya sólo le inserté manualmente el datetime con PHP con la fecha de pHP, no sé si es solución, pero me sirve XD

Comment: no lo hagas manual usa esto date_default_timezone_set("Etc/GMT+4") debes jugar con el +4  hasta que te dé tu hora

Answer (score -1):

Intenta crear un archivo php.ini en la raiz de tu servidor o carpeta www o public_html

```
[PHP]
date.timezone = "America/Mexico_City"
```

Comment: ¿Cómo hago eso? Ya subí la página a Hostinger (Host) y no sé cómo modificar el php ini de ahí

Comment: Al parecer con Hostinger lo puedes modifiar desde el Panel de Control https://www.hostinger.es/como/como-puedo-cambiar-el-archivo-php-ini ten precaución, es posible que existan otras configuraciones que puedas dañar.

Comment: Ya había checado, pero no me da la opción para cambiar el time zone :c